# Customising ClassWizard in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, classwizard

With the advent of VS2010 SP1, I'm once again looking at moving off VS2008 to the newer version.  The main reason for this, is that as a long time VC6 user, I find ClassWizard to be a great productivity tool, and welcome its long awaited return.  However, while ClassWizard works ok, I can't find any equivalent of the [.CLW file necessary for creating custom DDX routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57weza95%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  So for example, when regularly dealing with inputting lengths in VC6, I would have the following lines in my CLW file

```
ExtraDDXCount=1
ExtraDDX1=E;;Length;double;0.0;Length;Atlas:Use to store lengths;;&Length;s
```

which would let add length variables from ClassWizard.  Any idea if this is still supported in VS2010, or are we another year away from catching up with VC6?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "Not with VS2010".  I would like to see the ClassWizard support virtual methods from custom classes, but apparently it has a undocumented database of classes it knows about, or can figure out.